# Deriving volume of an n-ball given the expression for n-1 ball

Tags: volume, gamma-function, derivation-of-formulae

Given the expression for unit volume in n-1 dimention using Euler Gamma Function: $S_{n−1}=\frac{2π^{n/2}}{Γ(\frac n2)}$, I'd want to derive the expression for unit volume i n-dimentional space (which I found to be $S_n=\frac{π^{n/2}}{2Γ(\frac n2+1)}$). I cannot find the right steps to go from n-1 to n, because via standard Gamma Function transformations I get untransformable forms. How can you derive it?

Comment: easy   going from $n-2$   to $n,$   integral in polar coordinates

Comment: That seems to be the surface area, not quite the volume. My suggestion: inductively derive the *volume* of the unit ball, and then differentiate it to obtain the surface area of the unit sphere. Why does differentiating yield the surface area? That can be justified e.g. through the coarea formula, but that’s too complicated for me... (for now!)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#The_one-dimension_recursion_formula